# Oracle WebCenter 12C Portal Domain Configuration using Ansible

Tags: configuration, ansible, weblogic, portal, webcenter

I'm trying to configure Weblogic WebCenter 12C Portal Domain via Ansible on CentOS 7, but still can't find the way how to do it. So far I could install weblogic and weblogic portal with DB via Ansible. But I don't know how to configure Webcenter Portal. **/opt/app/middleware/oracle_common/common/bin/config.sh**
Have anyone already done this step via Ansible? If yes, please share with me this info if you have. I also tried to find any related info on google, but no luck, so I post my question here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you creating a WebLogic Portal env or a WebCenter Portal env ?
Once WebLogic Portal or WebCenter is installed with Ansible you have to create your domain with a WLST script.

Comment: Thanks for the respond Collin, I'm creating a WebCenter Portal env using Ansible. I also created domain via Ansible. My next step is configuration of the WebCenter Portal Domain, where I'm stuck. Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: You say "I also created domain via Ansible. My next step is configuration of the WebCenter Portal Domain" What difference do you make between these 2 domains ?

Comment: Yes that's correct, There is no difference, If you previously installed Weblogic 12C and Webcenter Portal12C you should know what I mean, I mean I need to configure Webcenter Portal 12C, domain is already installed I know how to do it manually, the question is how to do it using ANSIBLE (configure Webcenter Portal 12C) /opt/app/middleware/oracle_common/common/bin/config.sh

Comment: Thanks, but  WLST - is a WebLogic Scripting Tool. It's not giving me what I asked. I need to know how to run Webcenter configuration file via Ansible. I have a beginning of it, but I'm looking who has already done it 100%.

Comment: What do you mean by Wencenter configuration file ?

Comment: I mean when you run this shell config file /opt/app/middleware/oracle_common/common/bin/config.sh from the command line it will open a pop up X11 window check this link http://prasaddomala.com/oracle-webcenter-portal-12c-12-2-1-installation-configuration and find this part:  WebCenter Portal Domain Configuration, you will  see what I mean, thanks!

Comment: so i confirm you want to create a domain. config.sh is an interactive and  graphical tool. If you want to automate your domain creation you have to use WLST and create a script that will create your domain.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize I can use WLST in this case. Because I want to do it not manually, Ansible should do it automatically. But I have never use WLST, so If you know how to do, you are welcome to help, thank you Emmanuel.

Comment: You can start with the configToScript() WLST function. It will create a wlst script from an existning domain. Can be a good starting point to learn.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I found something like this https://www.techpaste.com/2012/05/offline-wlst-script-create-admin-server-managed-server-machine-cluster-weblogic and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iUMR2SEvRw